# How can I fetch a custom WP_query object

Tags: wordpress, custom-post-type, custom-wordpress-pages

After creating a new WP_query I receive a result, but can not understand how to fetch data from the "posts" element (ID, post_title etc):

```
$bo_query = new WP_query(
        array(
            'post_type' => 'condominium',
            'post_per_page' => -1
        )
    );
```

## ================================

```
object(WP_Query)#296 (49) {
  ["query"]=>
      array(2) {...}
    ["query_vars"]=>
      array(65) {...}
    ["tax_query"]=>
      object(WP_Tax_Query)#294 (6) {...}
    ["meta_query"]=>
      object(WP_Meta_Query)#291 (9) {...}
    ...
    ["posts"]=>
      array(1) {
        [0]=>
        object(WP_Post)#278 (24) {
          ["ID"]=>
          int(3)
          ["post_author"]=>
          string(1) "1"
          ...
          ["post_title"]=>
          string(27) "Кайзер Комфорт"
          ["post_excerpt"]=>
          string(0) ""
          ...
          ["post_name"]=>
          string(13) "kizer-comfort"
        }
    }
    ...
}
```

What I have to do to get ["post_title"], ["post_name"] etc from ["posts"] object?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use while loop for posts. See examples in [WP_Query](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_query/)

```
while($bo_query->have_posts()):
    $bo_query->the_post();

    echo get_the_ID();
    the_title();

endwhile;
```

Comment: Thank you, Maxim. I understand about template tags, but what I need to do to get ["post_name"] for example? Or ["post_author"]?

Comment: `get_the_title()` return post title (post name). And `get_the_author()` for return Author name. This loop will return you all data of post. See link which I included in my answer. There are present all answers on your questions. And on that site all template tags or functions that might help you to retrieve all data.